# What can a third interview be about?

Tags: interviewing

The first interview covered the typical questions like who you are, why they should hire you, weaknesses/strengths and general technical knowledge (the job is for a software development position).

The second interview was purely technical. It included questions about programming languages in general, programming features, whiteboard coding etc.

Then I was given a coding exercise to take home and hand it in. I was then told I passed the second interview and the coding exercise.

Subsequent to this I have been called in for a third and final interview with the CEO.

What could this possibly be about? I'm guessing salary and other practical stuff ?

I know this question may seem "too localized" but really what I'm trying to identify is the different parts of a technical interview.

Comment: Most probably they're going to negotiate terms and give you a formal offer.

Comment: [Cultural fit](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/how-to-hire-a-programmer.html).

Comment: If this is a small company it may show the CEO's involvement and commitment to having the right people fit into the culture. From my experience if its a large company it is a power move from a micromanaging CEO.

Comment: The answer to this question can only be speculation which is not a good fit for this Q&A Site.  If you have a specific problem to deal with involving a third interview please edit your question to ask that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, the third interview has two purposes:

1. Will the candidate be a good cultural fit?  Will he/she get along with the other team members and buy into the larger culture of the organization?
2. Information about benefits, working hours, dress code, and other relevant information about the day-to-day job that may not have been covered in the initial interviews.

Answer (score 3):

Typically as the other answers have stated it will be about the cultural fit, particularly if it's a smaller company/start-up. Read it like the "boss" of the company wants to feel comfortable that you will be able to fit in, make an impact and stay for the long-haul.

For bigger organisations typically it's about culture fit, but at times it can be a "final check" or probe of areas that you may have fallen short in the prior 2 interviews.

It might be worth checking with your recruiter or contact in the company on feedback to the previous 2 interviews before heading into this interview.

Comment: Hello Kenny, welcome to The Workplace, a Stack Exchange Q&A site. Typically, we try not to repeat what other answers have already said unless we can add more value. Would you be able to [edit] and add more details, perhaps even backing your answer up with evidence? Anything that provides some proof, including sharing your own personal experiences, helps us create a site where future visitors can rely on the content on our site. Good luck, and welcome!